# Sending HTTP POST Requests to WCF service from Swift

Tags: swift

I've used this code to connect to service

```
let login = ["FCAI":"1"]

let url = NSURL(string: "https//172.13.12.2/Image/serive.svc/GetImage")!

let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()

let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url)

do {

    let auth = try NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(login, options: .PrettyPrinted)


    request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")


    request.HTTPMethod = "POST"


    request.HTTPBody = auth


    let task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) -> Void in

        print("Got response \(response) with error \(error)")
        print("Done.")
    })


    task.resume()

} catch {

    print("Error")
}
```

But the response is always status 400
and the error is:

> The server encountered an error processing in the request.The exception message is 'There was an error deserializing the object of type system.string. End element 'root' from namespace ''.